# how to animate a UiView like opening a Book or Somthing Like expanding a view

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I need to animate my view like opening a Book or simply expanding a View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 5 you can use the new **Page view controller** which gives you a native support for the effect used in iBooks.

You can find it here:

[UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)

If you are registered as developer you can find a movie on using the new controller in the 2011 WWDC:

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Shani